# Create temp sails model

Tags: sails.js

For unit test I need to create temp model object without saving it in DB, just to have some instance method.

Example of model structure

```
//User.js - my model
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    firstName : { type: 'string' },

    lastName : { type: 'string' },


    getName: function () {
      return this.firstName + ':' + this.lastName;
    }
  }
};
```

I have next object

```
const testData = {
    firstName: 'Foo',
    lastName: 'Bar'
};
```

This line creates new record in db

```
User.create(testData);
```

Is it possible to avoid record creation? How can I do it?

Comment: You could setup a second DB connection, use sails-disk and point your model towards that by adding `connection: 'localDiskDb'`. This would obviously create the record in the local disk db but not in whatever other DB you are using. Alternatively you could add a beforeCreate lifecycle callback to the model and throw an error there preventing the save.

Comment: @Glen so, you propose in `Sails.lift` pass config with another connection? Like `Sails.lift{model{connection:'localDiskDb'}}`?
P.S: ATM I decide to create real record in DB in `before` Mocha callback and then destroy it in `after` callback. But it looks like a workaround. It would be really nice to have temp model instance without creation a record in DB.

Comment: So what your currently doing is similar to what I mentioned in my second point. What version of sails are you using?

Comment: @Glen in that project I use **0.12.14**. But my new projects I starts with version **v1**.

P.S: I use Mocha lifecycle callback, not Sails model.

Comment: So this question is relevant to v0.12.*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your initial question, functionality to switch off or on whether Sails actually creates a record in your database when you call Model.create() to the best of my knowledge does not exist, without a workaround as you have or I have described in the comments.

With that said, Sails does offer a simple solution for testing and development purposes.

As a convenience during development, Sails provides a built-in database adapter called sails-disk. This adapter simulates a real database by reading and writing database records to a JSON file on your computer's hard drive.

**If you are using a Sails version of < v1 [see documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings):**

Add a connection to the database in config/connection.js

```
localDiskDb: {
    adapter: 'sails-disk'
},
```

In the model you are testing, point the model towards the sails-disk connection.

```
...
module.exports = {
    connection: "localDiskDb",

    attributes: {
...
```

**If you are using Sails version >= v1 [see documentation](https://next.sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings):**

Instead, add sails-disk as a datastore in config/datastores.js

```
localDiskDb: {
    adapter: 'sails-disk'
},
```

And in the model you are testing, as above, point the model towards the sails-disk datastore.

```
...
datastore: 'localDiskDb',
...
```

Comment: But this is not good approach for modifying model, cause usually they must save data in db. So it's better to change model **connection|datastore** value to **localDiskDb** during `Sails.lift` in unit test.

Thanks for your help